# How to iterate over unique values in pandas and count frequency of associated values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that includes two columns of data as shown in the image below and I have added three additional columns corresponding to each of the 3 'types'.

[image]

My objective is the following: For each unique 'ID', I would like to count/tally the number of 'types' that occur through my df and add this value to the respective column.

Using the following line I can generate a count of each 'type' value but I am not sure how to iterate through each unique 'ID' and then add the 'type' counts to the new columns.

```
df.groupby('ID')['Type'].value_counts()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape output by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original by `ID` column:

```
df1 = df.join(df.groupby('ID')['Type'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0), on='ID')
```

Or use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `join`:

```
df1 = df.join(pd.crosstab(df['ID'], df['Type']), on='ID')
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for your help. Is it possible with these methods to set the names of the new columns (e.g. AC_1 or [random]) or is it best done after the fact with a column rename?

Comment: @Geo_J - What is reason for rename? If want to add some value then [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) or 
[`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) should help.